# How to Display value in Text widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I display the value on Text Widget since I am using `Getx`

I trying to display the value of balance using as map but fail (and I guess it is not efficient)
the method I know is using index but cant work using Text widget (need builder)

where I can get index ??? or any advice to make it work and efficient since this is to show all value in the balance

This is a text widget I work but need an index
[image: ScreenShot]

Here is the model, I want to show the value of balance in my Text widget
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: check your cashMain

Comment: Welcome to SO, would you please paste your code here instead of using screenshot to show the code. Some people (like me) can't access images due to national block of imgur.

Comment: thank you for your feedback 
its my first time using SO, I will edit soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Obx(
  () => ListView.builder(
  itemCount: cashMain.transData.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Text('${cashMain.transData[index].balance}')
  },
)
```